# What is the appropriate method of implementing a large pixel-editable drawing area in Qt

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, qimage, qpixmap

I am designing a paint application that allows you to create and edit very small sprites and tiles for an embedded application. [Here it is in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1zG6uwMEV8c). We're talking 8x8 pixel elements. This application allows you to edit single pixels at a time, and I'm currently in the process of modifying it to allow you to edit multiple sprites in a sheet at the same time in the editor, making the process of developing larger sprites that consist of multiple 8x8 sprites much easier.

In the exact same way the original NES operated, these sprites/tiles are limited to and defined by color palettes with a limit of 16 colors. Doing research, I found that `QImage`s can have their mode set to be indexed and an indexed color table can be assigned to them, which is precisely what I need.

As it stands, it currently uses `QGraphicsScene/View` to display a `QImage` in indexed mode. However the problem is that as the editable area increases, i.e. the more 8x8 elements you want to have editable at a given time, it would seem that performance would tank commensurately since you have to convert the entire `QImage` to a `QPixmap` and update the object in the `QGraphicsScene` every time a pixel is changed.

One could break up the scene into individual 8x8 `QImage`s and composite them to look like one unified image, however this seems more like a hack, and would definitely complicate the logic.

So, what is the proper approach to this problem?

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm inclined to agree; I added an edit with my problem statement. As far as I can tell, the only alternative would be to use the `QPainter` paradigm, which may require a lot more legwork as I don't care so much about the visual representation of the elements as I do the data representation, i.e. a sprite filled with the color red wouldn't be saved as an 8x8 matrix of a red RGB value, it would be an 8x8 matrix of whatever index the color red is in the 16-color palette.

Comment: Did you measure the performance loss? Your images seem small enough that updates should be fast enough.